# Restrict network access from within an openSuSE docker container

Tags: networking, opensuse, docker

How can I whitelist or blacklist a set of IP addresses to control which other hosts on the network can be reached from within a docker container (which is based on openSuSE)?

I already found an answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/922764/what-is-the-best-way-to-limit-the-ip-addresses-which-can-be-access-from-within-a), but I would prefer to

- not have to execute commands as root on the host
- make the rules apply only to one container
- (ideally) have the whitelist/blacklist configuration in the Dockerfile

My Dockerfile reads like this:

```
FROM opensuse:13.1
```

I build the image like this:

```
docker build -t mysuse .
```

Then I would like some IP addresses to be accessible from within the container:

```
docker run mysuse bash -c "ping -c1 192.168.1.1"
docker run mysuse bash -c "ping -c1 192.168.1.2"
```

and others to be not accessible:

```
docker run mysuse bash -c "ping -c1 192.168.1.3"
docker run mysuse bash -c "ping -c1 192.168.1.4"
```

Thanks for any help on this!